# console.log gives undefined on a variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a timer function (it calculates how many words were read in given time but my code doesn't work).

It says:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: startTime is not defined"

on line:

```
"testTime = (stopTime - startTime)/1000 + testTime;"
```

HTML

```
<button class="btn" id="start">Start Reading</button>
  <div id="page1" style="display: block;"><p class="title">
    Text goes here
 </div>
  <button class="btn" id="stop">Finished!</button>
  <span id="wordValue"></span>
  <span id="timeValue"></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function runTest(){

 testRunning = false;
 restart = false;
 var testTime = 0;

 jQuery('#start').click(function(){
   startTime = new Date().getTime();
   testRunning = true;
 });

  jQuery('#stop').click(function(){

    stopTime = new Date().getTime();
    testTime = (stopTime - startTime)/1000 + testTime;


    testRunning = false;
    // set wpm =  calculated words per minute
    wpm = Math.round(wordCount('#page1') / (testTime / 60));
    // set difference = calculated difference between words per minute and     national average (250)
    difference = Math.round(100*((wpm/250)-1));
    if (difference < 0) {
      difference = difference*-1 + '% slower';
    } else {
      difference = difference+'% faster';
    }
  });
```

Comment: No, you don't actually. This is javascript.

Comment: It's not a scope issue is it? try putting this outside the function `startTime = new Date().getTime();`

Comment: The main issue is that startTime is defined in the scope of the start event function and can't be seen from the stop event function. You need to add 'var startTime = 0' after the var testTime = 0 line

Comment: You need to define your variable globally if you want to use it like that. Just do a var startTime = 0; above your runTest function and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think startTime is not defined because it's a local variable to jQuery('#start').click. Try define startTime upper

```
var testRunning = false;
var restart = false;
var testTime = 0;
var startTime = 0; // here
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran this on jsfiddle and it worked fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/d3eqmbv5/

Just had to remove:

```
function runTest(){
```

And I made a fake `wordCount` function for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing parenthesis first if you look at this jsfiddle and tape F12, so what can be the next step ? to shutt the function right after or at the end of the complete block of code ?

```
function runTest(){
    testRunning = false;
    restart = false;
    var testTime = 0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qugp3fot/